# Nomenclature misbehavior, description missing

Tags: nomenclature

I have a problem with my nomenclature.
Using the following Code the output looks like in the pic below. If I delete the line `\setlength` I can see the whole description, but there are no or just one point in between. What I wanted is to have the description left aligned and points in between.

```
\documentclass
   [   fontsize=12pt,    
       paper=a4,         
   ]   {scrreprt}        

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\let\abbrev\nomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\makenomenclature


\nomenclature{LBS}{\textbf{L}ocation \textbf{B}ased \textbf{S}ervices}
\nomenclature{test}{tsetses}

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added an MWE.
€: after several edits, my pdf file is now just blank... Why...  Am into it

Comment: I compiled my bachelor thesis again, where I just this code and it worked just fine then. No I get the same result as above. So I think the problem lies somewhere in updated packages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you set `\nomlabelwidth`, the value of `\hsize` is still a very large value, as set by the `scrartcl` class.

You should use `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass
   [   fontsize=12pt,    
       paper=a4,         
   ]   {scrreprt}        

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\textwidth}

\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1\dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\makenomenclature


\nomenclature{LBS}{\textbf{L}ocation \textbf{B}ased \textbf{S}ervices}
\nomenclature{test}{tsetses}

\begin{document}

Some text

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better yet, move the setting at begin document:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\textwidth}}
```

Comment: Thanks :) 
I used this code in previous papers and it worked just fine. Weird